# DataTable automatically re-initializes itself

Tags: c#

Why does my `DataTable` automatically reset to `null` value inside of my event?

After the `for` loop ends the `DataTable` resets to null and doesn't keep the value in the public field. Even though I have another event that does the same thing but it can hold the `DataTable`.

```
Public DataTable d = new DataTable();

private void btnCSVgetter_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    emptyDataGrid();

    var csv   = new OpenFileDialog();
    csv.Title = "Select CSV to Upload";
    csv.DefaultExt = "*.csv";
    csv.Filter = "CSV files| *.csv";

    if (csv.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        string safeName = csv.SafeFileName;
        string filename = csv.FileName;
        string filedirectory = csv.FileName.Substring(0, filename.IndexOf(safeName));

        if (IsFileLocked(filename)) { MessageBox.Show("File is in use by another user, close and try again"); return; }

        var con = new OleDbConnection(String.Format("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source={0};Extended Properties=\"Text;HDR=YES;FMT=Delimited\"", filedirectory));
        var cmd = new OleDbCommand(String.Format("select * from [" + safeName + "]"), con);
        con.Open();

        var csvDA = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);
        var d = new DataTable();

        csvDA.Fill(d);
        DGVUpload.DataSource = d;

        con.Close();
        d.Columns.Remove("Symbol");

        foreach (DataColumn col in d.Columns)
        {
            if (col.ColumnName == "Ric Code")
                col.ColumnName = "Symbol";
            else if (col.ColumnName == "AveragePrice")
                col.ColumnName = "Avg_Price";
            else if (col.ColumnName == "Accounts")
                col.ColumnName = "ClientAcct";
            else if (col.ColumnName == "Executed")
                col.ColumnName = "Quantity";

        } // After this line datatable d resets to null

      // MoreCode...
 }
```

Comment: You've got two `d` variables - the one at the top and the one on line 25 in your code snippet.

Comment: You have a `d` field and a `d` variable in the method. Make sure you are referencing/using the correct one. This is a perfect example of why it is a good idea to use a naming convention like fields begin with `_` and variables are camel cased, etc.

Comment: You should expose properties, not fields; and give descriptive names to your variables: `public DataTable Data /* or something more descriptive in your case */ { get; }`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code snippet has two declarations of `DataTable d`:

```
Public DataTable d = new DataTable(); <---- here

private void btnCSVgetter_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    emptyDataGrid();

    OpenFileDialog csv = new OpenFileDialog();
    csv.Title = "Select CSV to Upload";
    csv.DefaultExt = "*.csv";
    csv.Filter = "CSV files| *.csv";

    if (csv.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        string safeName = csv.SafeFileName;

        string filename = csv.FileName;
        string filedirectory = csv.FileName.Substring(0, filename.IndexOf(safeName));

        if (IsFileLocked(filename) == true) { MessageBox.Show("File is in use by another user, close and try again"); return; }

        OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(String.Format("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source={0};Extended Properties=\"Text;HDR=YES;FMT=Delimited\"", filedirectory));
        OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(String.Format("select * from [" + safeName + "]"), con);
        con.Open();
        OleDbDataAdapter csvDA = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);
        DataTable d = new DataTable(); <----- here
        csvDA.Fill(d);
```

When you do this, the inner `if` statement is operating on the local `d` variable, not the class variable declared outside the method. Once the local `d` goes out of scope, the only `d` available to you is the one at the class level, which is empty.

Comment: I find that referring to `this.d` prevents the confusion!